# Вывод данных из txt на html страницу

Tags: golang

На днях начал изучать Go, но уже столкнулся с вроде бы простой, но неразрешимой для меня проблемой.

Условие: в структуре программки есть папка с текстовым файлом *test.txt*, все содержимое которого 3 строки, каждая не более 20 символов.

Задача: вывести содержимое этого файла на html страницу в таком же виде построчно.

Второй день пытаюсь решить разными методами, но никак не получается. Если у кого-то есть идеи как это реализовать - буду крайне признателен, желательно с кратким примером.

Вот код:

```
package main 

import (
    "fmt"
    "net/http"
    "io/ioutil"
)
func main() {

    http.HandleFunc("/", indexHandler)
    http.ListenAndServe(":8080", nil)
}

func indexHandler(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    b, err := ioutil.ReadFile("./data/test.txt")
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Print(err)
    }

    s := string(b)          
    var html = `<html><head><title>Проверка статуса</title></head><body> <h1>Статус</h1><div>%s</div></body></html>`
    fmt.Fprintf(w, html, fmt.Sprintf(s))
}
```

Comment: Покажите ваш код. И укажите что работает а что нет.

Comment: добавил код. Данные отображаются, но одной строкой, а нужно вывести построчно

Comment: А что, если выводить в```<pre> </pre>```, ведь у вас по факту текст с начальным форматированием. Альтернативой может послужить построчное чтение файла и вывод его строк, завернутых в ```<p></p>``` или ```<div></div>```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Во-первых, считывание всего файла через `ioutil.ReadFile` — антипаттерн. Лучше использовать буферизованный сканер. Во-вторых, вы забываете, что в HTML перенос строки делается через `<br/>`. В-третьих, вы не экранируете вывод, что чревато.

Вот код, который делает что вы хотите более оптимально и безопасно (обработка ошибок опущена для краткости).

```golang
http.HandleFunc("/", func(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    f, err := os.Open("./data/test.txt")
    // Check err.

    defer f.Close()

    _, err = io.WriteString(w, `<!DOCTYPE html><html><body>`)
    // Check err.

    s := bufio.NewScanner(f)
    for s.Scan() {
        _, err = io.WriteString(w, html.EscapeString(s.Text())+`<br/>`)
        // Check err.
    }

    if err = s.Err(); err != nil {
        // Check err.
    }

    _, err = io.WriteString(w, `</body></html>`)
    // Check err.
})
```

Код целиком: https://play.golang.org/p/T_d5g3StvQN.

Comment: то что нужно, спасибо!

Answer (score 0):

```
package main 

import (
    "fmt"
    "net/http"
    "io/ioutil"
    "html/template"
)

func main() {

    http.HandleFunc("/", indexHandler)
    http.ListenAndServe(":8080", nil)
}

func indexHandler(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
  const tpl = `<html><head><title>Проверка статуса</title></head><body> <h1>Статус</h1><div>{{.}}</div></body></html>`
    b, err := ioutil.ReadFile("./data/test.txt")
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Print(err)
    }
    s := string(b)          
    t, err := template.New("webpage").Parse(tpl)
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Print(err)
    }
    t.Execute(w, s)
}
```

попробуй так

Comment: не помогло. шаблон выводится, данных нет

Comment: так работает {{.}} подправил